# cant change Font color inside titleForHeaderInSection on iphone

Tags: iphone

How to change the Font color inside titleForHeaderInSection??

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tblView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {


//- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tblView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {


    //tabelView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];






    NSString *sectionName = nil;

    switch(section)
    {
        case 0:
            NSLog(@"ok");


            UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,30)];

            myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Zapfino" size: 14.0];
            myLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor grayColor];
            myLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1,1);
            myLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

            myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

            myLabel.text = @"DESCRIPTION";// not working i can only see value no color no font
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i did it like this

```
(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 44.0;
}
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// create the parent view that will hold header Label
UIView* customView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, 150.0, 44.0)]autorelease];






NSString *sectionName = nil;

switch(section)
{
case 0:

if(counter<=3)
NSLog(@"ok");

// create the buNSLog(@"ok");tton object
UILabel * headerLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]autorelease] ;
headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
headerLabel.opaque = NO;
headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
headerLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, 300.0, 44.0);

// If you want to align the header text as centered
// headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(150.0, 0.0, 300.0, 44.0);

headerLabel.text = @"Description"; // i.e. array element
[customView addSubview:headerLabel];


if(counter==7)

headerLabel.text = @""; // i.e. array element
[customView addSubview:headerLabel];

//sectionName = @"DES-";

break;

case 1:
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
    #pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table View Delegate Methods
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
 UILabel *sectionHeader = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectNull] autorelease];
 sectionHeader.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
 sectionHeader.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
 sectionHeader.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
 sectionHeader.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
 sectionHeader.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section %d", section];
 return sectionHeader;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
 return 40;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may only use "viewForHeaderInSection" delegate method to customize the header content